# onclick jquery add/remove class function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using single navigation file for all web pages, so i need to add or remove class based on click function. but somehow it's not working fine. any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").on("click", function() {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="nav-side-menu">
  <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
  <div class="menu-list">
    <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
      <li style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='new-patient.php';">
        <a><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>New Patient</a>
      </li>
      <li style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='returning-patient.php';">
        <a><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Returning Patient</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When page is navigate to other page then how you can manage active state from old page. for this you have to change your code

Comment: based on the url you can manage which li need to be active. This is only the solution

Comment: If you are using php ( from the window location attr in your code ), it's better to handle the class when rendering the page itself instead of handling it later on via javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script on every page to set this.

```js
var pageName = (function () {
  var a = window.location.href,
    b = a.lastIndexOf("/");
  return a.substr(b + 1);
} ());

$("#menu-content a").each(function () {
  if ($(this).attr('href') == pageName) {
    $(this).parents("li").addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-side-menu">
 <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>
 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
 <div class="menu-list">
  <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
   <li>
    <a href="new-patient.php">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>New Patient
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="returning-patient.php">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Returning Patient
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```